# Why does this code timeout on using break but not when I exit using loop counter variable?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, timeout, break

I saw some algorithm for a problem and rewrote it but I changed the `fast_count_segment` function's inner loop exit condition `j=n1` to the `break` statement,the code timed out. Why does this happen?

The code runs fine otherwise but when I submit to the online grader, it shows code timeout, but as soon as I replace `break` with `j=n1`, it passes.

Shouldn't both be doing the same thing?

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<int> fast_count_segments(vector<pair<int,int>> &v, vector<int> points) {
  vector<int> cnt(points.size());
  int n1=v.size(),n2=points.size(),i,j,count;
  for(i=0;i<n2;i++){
      count=0;
      for(j=0;j<n1;j++){
          if(points[i]>=v[j].first && points[i]<=v[j].second)
              count++;
          else if(points[i]<v[j].first)
              break;  //j=n1; Changed this statement to break
    }
    cnt[i]=count;
}
  return cnt;
}

int main() {
  int n, m,a,b;
  cin >> n >> m;
  vector<pair<int,int>> v;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >>a>>b;
    v.push_back(make_pair(a,b));
  }
  vector<int> points(m);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
    cin >> points[i];
  }
  sort(v.begin(),v.end());
  vector<int> cnt = fast_count_segments(v, points);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt.size(); i++) {
    cout << cnt[i] << ' ';
  }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the inputs for where you're getting different results? The code does look the same, so you'll need to provide additional information.

Comment: The thing is, the output is not wrong. But when I replaced the `j=n1` statement with `break` the code took 4.41 seconds to execute on psuedo-random input. Whereas previously it took < 2.5 seconds in same conditions.

Comment: Ok, How are you testing? Do you have optimizations enabled? How about finding a specific input that it takes noticeably longer for?

Comment: This code is submitted to my course online grader so I don't get the input value set. But the grader gives me a code timeout when I use break to exit the loop. Also, I've tried the code with another reference algorithm to get any differences but the output is always correct. I can give the sample inputs if that helps.

Comment: Sure, you could add a sample input, but that won't help much. If you can't find out the optimization level, and platform of the online grader, there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: @cigien don't want the solution. I just want to understand that why is this happening. If you look at the loop it's just exiting the loop by setting `j` to a value that  exits loop. but isn't break also doing the same? edit: The online grader is from coursera if that helps.

Comment: Yes, the program is *doing* the same thing, as your tests show. But your question is asking, "why is one doing it *faster*?" And that's not really a question that should be answered by only reading the code. (There are *many* factors that affect the run-time of a program).